# How could IDE index the library folder in the docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm, ide, webstorm

We usually use an IDE to develop programs.

However, the IDE is not smart enough to travel the library folder in the docker container.

So navigation to the source (for example, in PyCharm, you want to see the code in the installed third-party package) is usually not available. The IDE simply said "No module named xxxx".

How could this be fixed?

Comment: Can you use an ordinary Python virtual environment during development, and only use Docker for integration testing and deployment?

Comment: In general: the IDE needs a local copy of your code (or added in your project config and accessible from the IDE (e.g. via mount ro alike). If it's remote only then it will not index it.